# Javascript, Showing a lightbox on the window close

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

I would like to display a form on the page leaving not on the loading.

I'm doing like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    Test();
}
```

Test is a function that shows a form, the problem is that the page is closed without showing it. the only way I see is showing an alert box the prevent the page form exiting before the form is displayed and this is what I want to avoid.

Is there any way, plugin or library, to do that?

Comment: The idea is to have a `prompt()` inside the `onbeforeunload` handler. That's how all those "Do you really want to leave this page?" are implemented iirc.

Comment: Instead of the code you have, just use `window.onbeforeunload = Test` where `Test` is a function, assuming you want the return value of `Test` to be passed to the onbeforeunload event.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

If an user tells to his browser "Hey, I want to close this stupid tab", you can't force the browser to ignore the user and show a form instead of closing the tab.

That's because JavaScript runs client-side, so clients have full control.

Comment: Hi, you said "That's because JavaScript runs client-side, so clients have full control." Does this mean that there is a way to do it on the server side in PHP for instance?

Comment: @OussamaLord No, because if the client closes the tab, his browser won't make a connection to your site, so your php code won't be executed.

Answer (score 0):

not true, go to bounceexchange.com and view the page, then hover mouse over the X to close the tab and you'll be presented with a lightbox showing an offer before you go